# Spring Hibernate product - category relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, relationship

I've read many tutorials about spring-hibernate relationships but I'm a bit confused about how to use them in my case... I've product/category entities defined as follow:

**Product**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column
private int id;


@Column
private int category;
.
.
.
```

**Category**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column
private int id;

@NotEmpty
@Column
@Size (max = 25)
private String name;
.
.
.
```

So, I'd like in the product list page, under the voice "category" would appear the category name, and in the product form the category list...
In my case a product fits only one category so if I'm right it should be a @ManyToOne but I don't know how to implement this... in my product database I've the categoryId field, but if I mark the category entity field as @OneToMany it will not be stored to the db...

**EDIT**
I've changed like this (as suggested):
**Product.class**

```
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column
    @Size (max = 25)
    private String name;

    @Column
    @Size (max = 255)
    private String description;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    private Category category;
```

**Category.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column
    @Size (max = 25)
    private String name;


    @Column
    @Size (max = 255)
    private String description;


    //Here mappedBy indicates that the owner is in the other side
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addProduct(
            @ModelAttribute(value = "product") @Valid Product product,
            BindingResult result, ModelMap model, Category category) {




        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "forms/productForm";
        }

        try {
            category.addProduct(product);
            product.setCategory(category);

            // Add product to db
            productService.addProduct(product);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("/add/---" + e);
            return "redirect:/product/deniedAction/?code=0";
        }

        return "redirect:/admin/product/";

    }
```

I also added a @initbinder on the product controller to translate the data from the product form string to Category... but now when I save a product it automatically saves a category instead of attach the existing selected one...

Answer (score 4):

As the `Product` will have only one Category and `Category` will have a list of Products, you can relate these two by creating a `Foreign Key` in the Product table to refer to the primary key in the Category table:

```
Category Table: id, name, other fields...
Product Table: id, category_id (FK), and other fields.
```

And the mapping can be defined as below:

```
public class Category {

//Here mappedBy indicates that the owner is in the other side
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>(); 
...
}


public class Product {

//Here JoinColumn states that this entity is the owner of the relationship
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
private Category category;
...
}
```

The `mappedBy` attribute tells Hibernate that the collection is a mirror image of the many-to-one association on the other side. Its like telling Hibernate that it should propagate changes made at the `Product` end of the association to the database, ignoring changes made only to the `products` collection that you have in the `Category`. Thus if we only call `category.getProducts().add(product)`, no changes will be made persistent. As the association is bidirectional, you have to create the link on two sides, not just one.

For your convenience, you can add one `addProduct` method in the `Category` class to save the association:

```
public void addProduct(Product product) {
      product.setCategory(this);
      products.add(product);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I implemented your version and it seems to work... now I've another question: in the product form I choose the category with an "option" box... how can I save it in the product db table category_id field?

Comment: And how to display the correct category name inside the productlist jsp page?

Comment: create the product: `Product p=new Product()`,set the values of product. Then create category: `Category c=new Category()`, set the values of category and add product `p` to this category: `c.addProduct(p)`. Then pass the category `c` to `session.save(c)` method. this will save category `c` along with the product `p`.

Comment: Ok, but I've a problem, when I try to save the product from the product form I get this error back:
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type org.andreadorigo.webapp.entities.Category for property category; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.andreadorigo.webapp.entities.Category] for property category: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: You need to create an object of `Product` from the data (which are String values) that were submitted by the user. And the set this product to the set of `products` that you have in the `Category` by using `addProduct` method.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion but I get: spring hibernate Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation

Comment: can you edit your question. just add how did you create `Category` along with `Product` by adding product to the product list.

Comment: Ok I will, now I solved but when I add a product it add anothe category as well instead of attach the existing one...

Comment: when you are adding a new product to the product list of an existing category, you should use `session.update(category)` to update the category. This will update the existing category and will add a new product. You just need to make it sure that while passing `category` to session.update method, it should have the `id` value.

Comment: Before or after to add the product to the category product list?
If I do it before I get: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1;

Comment: If after:  Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in org.andreadorigo.webapp.entities.Product entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs), but I can see the category id if I do a categoryService.getId()

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a one-to-many relationship between Category and Product (one category has many products)

In Java (and OO generally) you'd expect the Category class to contain a list of Products, so the Category can be said to 'own' products.

In SQL it's the other way round - you'd expect Product table to hold a foreign key reference to a Category, so here, the Product can be said to 'own' a Category.

Looks like your using JPA, so you could have something like this:

Category class:

```
@Entity
public class Category {

  //other stuff...

  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="category")
  private Set<Product> products;

}
```

Product class:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

  //other stuff...

  @ManyToOne
  private Category category;
}
```

Comment: Great! This is the missing piece I needed! By the way, have I to remove the category id from product db table right? And... have I to also change the category db one?

Comment: You should't need to create tables yourself. Hibernate can do that for you - the schema is generated by the annotations (if necessary) when you run it. Unless you already have data you need to keep, I suggest dropping all tables, running the code, and then inspecting the newly created tables and FK constraints to see if they are as you expected.

Comment: I think hibernate does it for me if I declared the auto.dll

Answer (score 0):

so you have this:

```
  Product{
    atributtes...
    @ManyToOne
    Category category; --so every product has a category 
    }

  Category {
     attributtes...
     @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name="id_Product")
     private List<Product> products;
    }
```

try this, if not we can look another solution..

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you should use @ManyToOne because "...a product fits only one category...".

In Product entity declare a Category field instead of int category and annotate it with @ManyToOne. Also add @JoinColumn to specify the name of product.category_id column in the database.

**Product**:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column
private int id;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private Category category;
.
.
.
```